# Get branch to which a Github Pull Request comment belongs

Tags: github, travis-ci, webhooks, pull-request

I'm building the Github PR comment to Travis build thing from my previous question (since it does not seem to exist), but I'm running into the problem:

- Github sends a webhook call for **Issue comments** (which is how they call PR comments)
- That comment payload has an `issue` object attached to it.
- There is a lot of stuff in the `issue` but information about what branch the changes are in is not one of them.
- I also don't see an obvious way of retrieving the branch.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I wasn't missing anything, Github answered:

> Thanks for sharing your thoughts -- I'll pass them along to the team
>   working on webhooks but I don't expect any changes here in the near
>   future. For now, for each pull request that's opened -- you can save
>   the head and base branch information on your end. Then, once you
>   receive an issue comment webhook delivery, you will know which pull
>   request and which branches it is about without needing to call the
>   API.